# Why does this code return false instead of true?

Tags: java, return

I have a code that checks if a wordpuzzle contains a certain word.
This is the testclass:

```
package application;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

/**
 * Test class for the implementation of the {@link WordPuzzle}
 *
 */
public class WordPuzzleTest {

    WordPuzzle myPuzzle = null;

    /**
     * This function will initialize the myPuzzle variable before you start a new test method
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        try {
            this.myPuzzle = new WordPuzzle("VNYBKGSRORANGEETRNXWPLAEALKAPMHNWMRPOCAXBGATNOMEL", 7);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
                System.out.println("An exception has occured");
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }

    }

    /**
     * Test the constructor of the {@link WordPuzzle} class
     */
    @Test
    public void testWordPuzzle() {
            assertNotNull("The object failed to initialize", this.myPuzzle);
            char[][] expectedArray = {{'V','N','Y','B','K','G','S'},
                                 {'R','O','R','A','N','G','E'},
                                 {'E','T','R','N','X','W','P'},
                                 {'L','A','E','A','L','K','A'},
                                 {'P','M','H','N','W','M','R'},
                                 {'P','O','C','A','X','B','G'},
                                 {'A','T','N','O','M','E','L'}};
            assertArrayEquals(expectedArray, this.myPuzzle.getLetterArray());
    }

    /**
     * Test to search for some words...
     */
    @Test
    public void testSearchWord() {
            assertFalse("The word SOFTWARE is found, and may not be found", this.myPuzzle.searchWord("SOFTWARE"));
            assertTrue("The word BANANA is not found", this.myPuzzle.searchWord("BANANA"));
    }

}
```

This is the code I wrote to find that certain word:

```
package application;

public class WordPuzzle {

    private String puzzle;
    private int numRows;
    private char [][] puzzleArray = new char[numRows][numRows];

    public WordPuzzle(String puzzle, int numRows) {
        super();
        this.puzzle = puzzle;
        this.numRows = numRows;

        puzzleArray = new char[numRows][numRows];
        char[] puzzleChar;
        puzzleChar=puzzle.toCharArray();

        int index=0;
        int i=0;
        int j=0;
        while (i<numRows) {
            while (j<numRows) {
                puzzleArray[i][j] = puzzleChar[index];
                j++;
                index++;
            }
            i++;
            j=0;
        }   
    }

    public Object[] getLetterArray() {
        return puzzleArray;
    }

    public boolean searchWord(String word) {
        char[] wordChar;
        wordChar = new char[word.length()];
        int xaxis=0;
        int yaxis=0;
        int index=0;
        boolean wordFound=false;

        while (yaxis<numRows) {
            while (xaxis<numRows) {
                /**
                 * Find first matching letter
                 */
                if (puzzleArray[yaxis][xaxis]!=wordChar[index]) {
                    xaxis++;
                }
                else {
                    int xinit=xaxis;
                    int yinit=yaxis;

                    /** 
                     * Check left
                     */
                    while (xaxis>-1 && puzzleArray[yaxis][xaxis]==wordChar[index]) {
                        if (index==word.length()-1) {
                            wordFound=true;
                            return wordFound;
                        }
                        else {
                            xaxis--;
                            index++;
                        }
                    }
                    xaxis=xinit;
                    yaxis=yinit;
                    index=0;

                    /** 
                     * Check up
                     */
                    while (yaxis>-1 && puzzleArray[yaxis][xaxis]==wordChar[index]) {
                        if (index==word.length()-1) {
                            wordFound=true;
                            return wordFound;
                        }
                        else {
                            yaxis--;
                            index++;
                        }
                    }
                    xaxis=xinit;
                    yaxis=yinit;
                    index=0;

                    /** 
                     * Check down
                     */
                    while (yaxis<numRows && puzzleArray[yaxis][xaxis]==wordChar[index]) {
                        if (index==word.length()-1) {
                            wordFound=true;
                            return wordFound;
                        }
                        else {
                            yaxis++;
                            index++;
                        }
                    }
                    xaxis=xinit;
                    yaxis=yinit;
                    index=0;

                    /** 
                     * Check right
                     */
                    while (xaxis<numRows && puzzleArray[yaxis][xaxis]==wordChar[index]) {
                        if (index==word.length()-1) {
                            wordFound=true;
                            return wordFound;
                        }
                        else {
                            xaxis++;
                            index++;
                        }
                    }
                    xaxis=xinit;
                    yaxis=yinit;
                }
            }
            yaxis++;
            xaxis=0;
        }
    return wordFound;
    }
}
```

When I run the test, it will say that it didn't found the word "BANANA". I can't find my mistake. It should return

```
wordFound=true
```

when checking downwards. But it doesn't...

Comment: You can use the debugger and check the execution flow of your program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't initialize the char array with the input String.

Change

```
public boolean searchWord(String word) {
    char[] wordChar;
    wordChar = new char[word.length()];
    ...
```

to

```
public boolean searchWord(String word) {
    char[] wordChar = word.toCharArray();
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In the searchWord method (in WordPuzzle class), you are using an array of char :

```
wordChar = new char[word.length()];
```

But you never set the value of your String variable "word" into it (you just gave it its length).

Then, this if condition :

```
if (puzzleArray[yaxis][xaxis]!=wordChar[index]) {
                xaxis++;
            }
```

is always true, and your method is just incrementing variables and checking this useless condition, and finishes with a false return.

Try replacing
 `wordChar = new char[word.length()];`
with

```
wordChar = word.toCharArray();
```